# Hadoop fs -ls command to get 1st 10 files

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I have a hadoop commnd like this :

```
hadoop fs -ls /user/hive/warehouse/mashery_db.db/agg_per_mapi_stats_five_minutes/ | sort | awk  '{ if (index($8, ".hive") == 0 && $6 <= "'"2016-02-10"'" && $7 <= "'"05:00"'") print $8 }'
```

I want to get 1st 10 values from it,instead of getting all the files in the directory.

Comment: By values, you mean first 10 files? Also, do they have any patterns these files?

Comment: @SethuSabarish no pattern..and yes 1st ten files.

Comment: No pattern? Then why include the awk part?

Comment: Also this question is generalized as "how to get the top ten lines from standard output"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use

```
hadoop fs -ls /path/of/hdfs/location/ | head -10
```

that will work.

Comment: yup, i recognized it later.

Answer (score 3):

Add another pipe on the end to `head -10`

```
hadoop fs -ls /stuff | sort | awk whatever | head -10
```